# The specified formula cannot be entered because it contains more values,references and/r names than are allowed to the current file format

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to build a spreadsheet showing how many staff are in per 15 increments of the day.  I have used:

`=COUNTIF(c8:c41,"7")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"7.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"7.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"7.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"8.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"8.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"8.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"8.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"9.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"9.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"9.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"9.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"10.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"10.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"10.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"10.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"11.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"11.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"11.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"11.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"12.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"12.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"12.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"12.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"13.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"13.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"13.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"13.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"14.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"14.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"14.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"14.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"15.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"15.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"15.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"15.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"15.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"16.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"16.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"16.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"16.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"17.00")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"17.15")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"17.30")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"17.45")+COUNTIF(c8:c41,"18.00")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"11.00")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"11.15")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"11.30")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"11.45")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"12.00")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"12.15")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"12.30")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"12.45")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"13.00")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"13.15")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"13.30")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"13.45")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"14.00")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"14.15")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"14.30")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"14.45")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"15.00")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"15.15")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"15.30")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"15.45")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"16.00")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"16.15")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"16.30")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"16.45")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"17.00")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"17.15")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"17.30")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"17.45")-COUNTIF(d8:d41,"18.00")`

however I know get this error message. I need to go up to 21:00 hours.

Please can anyone help - I cannot think of a way around this :(

Comment: Have you thought of using `COUNTIFS`? `=COUNTIFS(C8:C41,">="&7,C8:C41,"<="&21)` will count all values between 7 and 21. I'm not sure what time format you use, but you should be able to adjust the formula easily enough.

Comment: It's very unlikely we can fix that formula for you without knowing your data. Please post some sample data so we might be able to suggest something.

Comment: Employee starts at 09:00 finishes at 18:00
Employee starts at 16:00-22:00

spreadsheet counts I have 2 bodies in at 16:00, 2 At 17:00 and then one at 18:00  - does that make sense?

Comment: @robo - It's better to add any information by [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1351359/edit)) you question instead of using comments. What you say makes sense, but seeing how your data is set up would help us help you better.

Comment: Your formula returns a single answer.  If that is what you want, just `SUM` the hours worked for each employee, between the start and stop times, and multiply by 96 or 4 depending on whether the hours are integers, or Excel "times"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of a simple method I used for my spreadsheet doing the same thing.

[image: Spreadsheet sample]

Columns `F` to `BJ` represent each 15 minute block upto 21:00 and the cells were conditionally formatted to

- fill with a colour and
- change the text colour to the same as the fill colour
- when `the cell value = 1`.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Cell `F2` has the following formula
`=IF(AND(F$1>=$C2,F$1<$D2),1,"")`

(If cell `F1` is >= the `start time` and cell `F1` < `finish time`, then put a `1` in the cell)

and the formula was dragged filled across to column BJ and down to the bottom of the list of people.

As there is now a 1 for each person within the 15 minute block they are in, it is a matter of summing the column of 1s with a `SUM()` formula (in row 4 within the screeshot).